# How to optimize writing a list of dictionaries using json dump into a file?

Tags: python, json, python-3.x

Currently I'm having the following implementation to write a `list` of `dictionaries` into a file. The `file_limit_counter` below would be initialized to 0 whereas the `file_limit` will be initialized to let's say 50 for now. So whenever the counter becomes equal to the file limit, it'll start writing the output into a new file. The counter approach is to break the output into multiple files:

```
self.file = self.generate_new_micro_file_name()
for response_dict in all_response_dict_list:
    if file_limit_counter == file_limit:
        self.propagate_log_msg('wrote {} records '.format(file_limit))
        self.file = self.generate_new_micro_file_name()
        file_limit_counter = 0
    with open(self.file, 'a', encoding="utf8") as open_out_file:
        json.dump(response_dict, open_out_file)
        open_out_file.write('\n')
    file_limit_counter += 1
```

The list `all_response_dict_list` would contain something like this:

```
somelist = [{"Name":"a1","Age":"24"},{"Name":"a2","Age":"26"}]
```

and my intention is to have something like this on my output file:

```
{"Name":"a1","Age":"24"}
{"Name":"a2","Age":"26"}
...
```

This above approach works fine. But when it comes to a large set of dictionaries for example 5000 it tends to slow down a bit (it takes approximately 10 mins). So it'll be helpful if someone have already come across this kind of scenario. I think it would take less time if we can do the same thing above in parallel i.e. writing multiple dictionaries at the same time into the same file rather than writing one by one.

Comment: This is a case where (I would argue) that the Work Manager approach to opening the output file is inappropriate. Every time you open the same file the os has to seek to the end before you can write data into it. So, open it once then close it when you've reached your limit, then open your next file

Comment: thank you @DarkKnight you're spot on there. I'm also on the same page with you, but was just putting it out loud to see whether there're any other options to do it.

Comment: By doing what DarkKnight suggested, I can write 50,000 names in 1.1 seconds.  I'll post below.

Comment: @TimRoberts 1.1s? Are you using an abacus ;-)

Comment: Close, it's Windows.  It takes a second to open and write 1,000 files.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A slight variation on this theme that runs in <0.5s on my machine:-

```
import json
import time


all_response_dict_list = [{'name': f'a{i}', 'age': i} for i in range(50_000)]
file_limit = 50


def fgen():
    fnum = 1
    while True:
        yield f'/Users/andy/j/base{fnum}.json'
        fnum += 1


def main():
    G = fgen()
    for offset in range(0, len(all_response_dict_list), file_limit):
        with open(next(G), 'a') as outfile:
            for rd in all_response_dict_list[offset:offset+file_limit]:
                json.dump(rd, outfile)
                outfile.write('\n')


if __name__ == '__main__':
    start = time.perf_counter()
    main()
    end = time.perf_counter()
    print(f'Duration={end-start:.4f}s')
```

Comment: This is not materially different from my answer.

Comment: Except that it closes the file handles and runs in almost half the time

Comment: Your code runs in exactly the same time as mine on my system.  The files all get closed as soon as the new one is opened and the old reference gets dropped.

Answer (score 1):

This does 50,000 names to 1,000 files in 1.1 seconds, by keeping the file open rather than doing open/close 50 times.

```
import json
import time

# Generate.

part1 = time.time()

all_response_dict_list = []
for i in range(50000):
    all_response_dict_list.append( {'name':f'a{i}', 'age':str(i) } )

part2 = time.time()
print( part2 - part1 )

# Write.

file_limit = 50
file_limit_counter = 0
fnum = 0

def generate_new_micro_file_name():
    global fnum
    fnum += 1
    return f'base{fnum}.json'

open_out_file = open(generate_new_micro_file_name(), 'a', encoding='utf8')
for response_dict in all_response_dict_list:
    if file_limit_counter == file_limit:
        open_out_file = open(generate_new_micro_file_name(), 'a', encoding='utf8')
        file_limit_counter = 0
    json.dump(response_dict, open_out_file)
    open_out_file.write('\n')
    file_limit_counter += 1

print( time.time() - part2 )
```

Comment: You don't seem to be closing the output files. They may be incomplete

Comment: This appears to open all 50000 files at once, which seems sloppy and could be an issue on some platforms. Regardless, while this code may answer the question, which might provide some limited, immediate help. A [proper explanation](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) would greatly improve its long-term value by showing why this is a good solution to the problem and would make it more useful to future readers with other, similar questions.

Comment: Each file will, of course, will be closed as soon as the new file is opened, releasing the previous reference.

Comment: @Tim: Opening a new file by assigning a new value to the variable does not necessarily close the previous file.

Comment: In CPython, it absolutely does.  In some of the other implementations, the close might be delayed until the garbage collector runs, but they certainly will be closed.

Comment: They may eventually get closed, but meanwhile there will be 50K of them open at the same time.

Answer (score 1):

You could split your list into chunks of size **file_limit** and then write to the files at once.

Try:

```
chunks = [all_response_dict_list[i: i+file_limit] for i in range(0, len(all_response_dict_list), file_limit)]

for chunk in chunks:
    with open(self.generate_new_micro_file_name()) as outfile:
        json.dump(chunk, outfile)
```